# .Net Core and WebCrypto handshake

Tags: encryption, .net-core, rsa, webcrypto-api

I would like to initialize a secure channel between a server (.NET Core 3.1) and a client browser application (JS using WebCryptoAPI) with the following steps:

1. server sends its public RSA key `K` to the client
2. client encrypts its public RSA key `L` using `K` and sends it to the server
3. server decrypts the message to obtain `L`, encrypts an AES key using `L`and sends it back to the client
4. client decrypts the message containing the AES key and they talk securely ever after

So far, I managed to reach the second step:

### TypeScript Client requests server's public key

```js
const hubConnection = new SignalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/hub/myhub").build();
Crypto.generateKey({name: "RSA-OAEP", 
                    modulusLength: 2048, 
                    publicExponent: new Uint8Array([1, 0, 1]),
                    hash: "SHA-512"}, 
                    true,
                    ["encrypt", "decrypt"])
.then(key => {
    clientRSA = key;
    console.debug("Client RSA:", clientRSA);
    return hubConnection.start();
})
.then(() => hubConnection.invoke("requestServerKey"));
```

### C# Backend creates a new key and answers

```cs
public class MyHub : Hub<IMyHub>
{
    public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        using var rsa = RSA.Create(KeySize);
        //store it to in-memory DB
    }
}

public void RequestServerKey()
{
    RSA rsa = DB.Get(Context.ConnectionId);
    Clients.Caller.SetServerKey(Convert.ToBase64String(rsa.ExportSubjectPublicKeyInfo()));
}
```

### Typescript client receives the public key

```js
hubConnection.on('setServerKey', (data: string) => {
    const buffer = Uint8Array.from(atob(data), c => c.charCodeAt(0));
    Crypto.importKey("spki", buffer, { name: "RSA-OAEP", hash: "SHA-512"}, false, ['encrypt'])
    .then(rsaPublicKey => { //by some reason I can't pull this promise out to the zero level
        serverKey = rsaPublicKey;
        return Crypto.exportKey("spki", clientRSA.publicKey);
    })
    //THE FOLLOWING CALL FAILS
    .then(clientPublicKey => Crypto.encrypt({name: "RSA-OAEP"}, serverKey, clientPublicKey))
    .then(message => {
        const str = btoa(String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(message)));
        hubConnection.invoke("requestSymmetricKey", str);
    })
});
```

It seems that the public key of the server is imported successfully by the `WebCrypto API` but it fails then when I try to use it to encrypt the client's public key before sending it to the server. I also tried the `wrapKey` method but the errors were the same. I get the following:

```
index.js:1 Uncaught Error: The error you provided does not contain a stack trace.
    at L (index.js:1)
    at Y (index.js:1)
    at index.js:1
    at index.js:1
    at l (index.js:1)

home:1 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException
Promise.then (async)
...
```

So I am looking for any kind of hint what could be the issue here. I tried various combinations of initialization parameters, looked at all intermediate values but nothing gives me a hint what could be wrong. Except I made some stupid copy error, my code should follow these examples:

- https://gist.github.com/QingpingMeng/f51902e2629fc061c6b9fc9bb0f3f57b
- https://github.com/diafygi/webcrypto-examples#rsa-oaep---encrypt

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Why do you encrypt the client's public key (Step 2)?

Comment: I might have used the wrong terms. Both the server and the client generate a pair of asymmetric keys (unique for each session) which they should use to securely exchange the common symmetric AES key. So technically only the "public" key of the server is the only unprotected one.

Comment: Public keys do not need to be encrypted, hence the term _public_ (however, the ownership of a public key must be proven, typically with a certificate, otherwise a man-in-the-middle attack is possible). The only key that needs to be encrypted is the symmetric key. Maybe I misunderstand you.

Comment: I am thinking about your question since then. Basically you suggest to reduce it to: 1) send the server my pubilc key 2) server responds with an encrypted symmetric key 3) we talk securely ever after. So I now I am trying to figure out if there is no security flaw in the simplified routine...

Comment: If the server uses your public key for encryption, only you as the owner of the associated private key can decrypt. This is guaranteed. A problem arises when an attacker intercepts your public key during the exchange and sends their own public key to the server instead (man-in-the-middle attack). Take one more look at the concepts of hybrid encryption and PKI (public key infrastructure).

Comment: Thank you, I decided to go with the simplified version with the symmetric key generated by the client and sent encoded with server's public key directly to the server. The server's public key will be additionally published to an independent "authority" to allow verification. That should mitigate the man-in-the-middle for my case well enough.

Answer (score 1):

So I found the solution with the help of the following post: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/42097/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-the-plaintext-message-for-rsa-oaep

Since the server's public key is 2048 bits and using SHA-512, the maximum message length is just 126 bytes. However, the message I tried to transmit was 294 bytes. It's a pity that API does not have a dedicated error message for this, as it can be easily checked automatically.

Following the discussion in the comments to my question I have simplified the procedure to:

1. server exposes its public RSA key within its API and posts it (or its hash) to an additional independent location for verification
2. client generates a symmetric AES key, encrypts it by server's public RSA key and sends it over
3. server decrypts the symmetric AES key using its private RSA key and they talk securely ever after

Now I hope to get it all work betweeen JS and C#.